# TightVNC viewer closes erraticly after starting a program

Tags: networking, vnc, vncviewer

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and connect with TightVNC viewer from Windows 10. It seems to go well, until I start a program, for example an internet explorer. It then just closes, with the message: "Connection has been gracefully closed".

[image]

Trying to restart it, will not work. As I get:

[image]

A selection of log lines occuring at the same time:

**Auth.log**:

```
Jul 28 10:54:31 MediaPC polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.17, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale nl_NL.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

**Syslog**:

```
Jul 28 10:54:30 MediaPC kernel: [ 7914.440909] Xtightvnc[1355]: segfault at 7fff021c2000 ip 0000000000448a2e sp 00007fff021bf680 error 6 in Xtightvnc[400000+178000]
Jul 28 10:54:31 MediaPC kernel: [ 7914.838691] Network Thread[2002]: segfault at 0 ip 000000000135a584 sp 00007fda03e5a580 error 4 in spotify[400000+1fd0000]
```

**Apport.log**:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 2993) Thu Jul 28 10:54:31 2016: called for pid 1355, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 2993) Thu Jul 28 10:54:31 2016: executable: /usr/bin/Xtightvnc (command line "")
ERROR: apport (pid 2993) Thu Jul 28 10:54:31 2016: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 2993) Thu Jul 28 10:54:31 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 2997) Thu Jul 28 10:54:31 2016: called for pid 1543, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 2997) Thu Jul 28 10:54:31 2016: executable: /usr/share/spotify/spotify (command line "/usr/share/spotify/spotify\ %U")
ERROR: apport (pid 2997) Thu Jul 28 10:54:31 2016: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 2997) Thu Jul 28 10:54:33 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

**Kern.log**:

```
Jul 28 10:54:30 MediaPC kernel: [ 7914.440909] Xtightvnc[1355]: segfault at 7fff021c2000 ip 0000000000448a2e sp 00007fff021bf680 error 6 in Xtightvnc[400000+178000]
Jul 28 10:54:31 MediaPC kernel: [ 7914.838691] Network Thread[2002]: segfault at 0 ip 000000000135a584 sp 00007fda03e5a580 error 4 in spotify[400000+1fd0000]
```

Comment: If i may ask, why use tightvnc? i use nomachine for the rdp between my pc, laptop, Phone, raspberry pi and ubuntu tower :)

Comment: Because I ask on this forum, what should I use. Somebody said use tightvnc, so I did.

Comment: it is one of the possible options ofcourse, it all comes with its pro's and con's :) but I cant help with tightvnc, I am sorry